# ¿Cómo controlar el número de dígitos en un output de regresión lineal en R?

Tags: r, funciones, print

Sé que esta pregunta se ha hecho en múltiples espacios (en particular en el sitio en inglés). Sin embargo, he intentado muchas alternativas y ninguna parece funcionar; por esa razón es que hago esta publicación.

Básicamente, cuando uno quiere controlar el número de digitos en un output cualquiera, se puede usar

```
options(digits= número entre 1 y 22)
```

La cuestión es que acabo de notar que no puedo hacer nada para alcanzar un cierto número de dígitos específicamente en la columna de coeficientes de un modelo de regresión lineal. Si quito la notación científica con `scipen=999` lo que sucede es que R me rebota demasiados dígitos. Por ejemplo:

```
> options(digits=5, scipen=999)
> print(summary(reg))

Call:
lm(formula = tcd ~ time + I(time^2))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5486 -0.4678 -0.0793  0.3824  2.7576 

Coefficients:
                Estimate   Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 13.963211021  0.081454725   171.4 <0.0000000000000002 ***
time         0.018902928  0.000477403    39.6 <0.0000000000000002 ***
I(time^2)   -0.000017128  0.000000587   -29.2 <0.0000000000000002 ***
```

Sin embargo, si intento algo como:

```
> options(digits=5, scipen=0)
> print(summary(reg))

Call:
lm(formula = tcd ~ time + I(time^2))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5486 -0.4678 -0.0793  0.3824  2.7576 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.40e+01   8.15e-02   171.4   <2e-16 ***
time         1.89e-02   4.77e-04    39.6   <2e-16 ***
I(time^2)   -1.71e-05   5.87e-07   -29.2   <2e-16 ***
```

Tengo notación científica y, por más que intento, no puedo lograr que el output muestre valores comprensibles.

Mi problema es en específico con la regresión lineal, ya que por ejemplo, al llamar un auto.arima, todo está en orden:

```
> options(digits=5, scipen=0)
> summary(tcd_aar)
Series: tcd 
ARIMA(2,1,2) 

Coefficients:
        ar1     ar2     ma1    ma2
      1.064  -0.698  -0.953  0.550
s.e.  0.125   0.118   0.147  0.137

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0203:  log likelihood=417.92
AIC=-825.85   AICc=-825.77   BIC=-802.51
```

En concreto, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo logro modificar el output en la regresión lineal? ¿Es necesario cambiar parámetros en `print.lm` o algo similar?

Agradezco cualquier orientación al respecto.

Comment: No es respuesta, es una aproximación alternativa: usar la función screenreg( ) del paquete texreg . Para mi gusto las tablas de regresión salen más legibles que con summary y tiene otras opciones como pasar una lista de modelos para compararlos. Además tiene un argumentos digits= que funciona. Lo de print.summary.lm es un misterio para mí, porque en el código refiere al argumento digits, pero en el output no parece tener efecto. Podés ver el código con getAnywhere(print.summary.lm). Saludos!

Comment: Revisaré lo que me comentas. ¡Saludos!